# Solr: Adding cores using a configSet in a SolrCloud setup does not work

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrj, solrcloud, solrconfig

I have a SolrCloud (v5.2) setup with 2 different cores [`users, docs`] working properly.

Now I need to be able to dynamically add new cores that are configuration-wise identical to the `docs` core that already exists. I don't want to duplicate the configuration (I tried an it works OK) as I need to actually share the `synonyms.txt` and some other files that constantly change.

I think that I need "configsets" but I cannot get them to work. I uploaded the "template" conf using this command:

```
sh zkcli.sh -zkhost zk1:2181 -cmd upconfig -confname template -confdir /home/user1/template/conf
```

And then I tried to create a new core using the `template` configset like this:

```
http://solr1:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&configSet=template&name=test1
```

But I get this error:

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'test1': Unable to create core [test1] Caused by: Could not find configName for collection test1 found:[users, docs, template, .system]
```

I think that I have some missing knowledge on how configsets work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share a configuration for a Core and just create a new Collection. Any changes to the configuration will affect all Collections.

Use this call to create the new Collection:

```
http://solr1:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=test1&collection.configName=docs&numShards=1
```

Answer (score 0):

the default path to directory with configset is $SOLR_HOME/configsets ie in my example is /opt/solr/solr-5.4.0/server/solr/configsets. This path can be configured in solr.xml.

So, if you use the default path for configset then this

```
sh zkcli.sh -zkhost zk1:2181 -cmd upconfig -confname template -confdir /home/user1/template/conf
```

should be replaced with

```
sh zkcli.sh -zkhost zk1:2181 -cmd upconfig -confname template -confdir /home/user1/......../../../configsets
```

just replace this path /home/user1/......../../../configsets with your correct path for the configsets

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried what you said with the command like this: sh zkcli.sh -zkhost zk1:2181 -cmd upconfig -confname template -confdir /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets but the result is the same. 
In the /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets folder we have 4 folders (3 defaults and mine): basic_configs  data_driven_schema_configs  sample_techproducts_configs  template

Comment: can you try sh zkcli.sh -zkhost zk1:2181 -cmd upconfig -confname template -confdir /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/template/conf ?

Comment: Same result: "Could not find configName for collection test3 found: ...". I think there is something about letting Solr where the config sets are in ZK that I don't quite get.